# What is it called when a block returns a value? 

Tags: c++, c, gcc, terminology

I came across this code recently, which doesn't look legal to me (but gcc compiles it). I don't so much mind the construction as want a name for it:

```
#define MAX(a,b) \
({ \
    typeof(a) _a = (a); \
    typeof(b) _b = (b); \
    (_a > _b) ? (_a) : (_b); \
})
```

Apparently, the last statement's value is being returned as the "value" of the expression bounded by the namespace.

Edit: Thanks for the answers guys. Turns out this is an extension to plain C called Statement Expressions.

Comment: There is no "namespace" here. If you don't see a `namespace` keyword, it isn't a namespace.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is **not a namespace**, **it is a macro** which returns maximum of two values.
`\` at the end of the statements is use to append multiple statements and create a multi-line macro.

The code is not standard C++ but it compiles in gcc because it is supported as an **[gcc compiler extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs)**.

Good Read:

**Statement Expressions:**
A compound statement is a sequence of statements enclosed by braces. In GNU C, a compound statement inside parentheses may appear as an expression in what is called a `Statement expression`.

```
         .--------------.
         V              |
>>-(--{----statement--;-+--}--)--------------------------------><
```

The value of a statement expression is the value of the last simple expression to appear in the entire construct. If the last statement is not an expression, then the construct is of type void and has no value.

Note: This excerpt is taken from IBM XL C/C++ v7.0 documentation.

Comment: I don't think `int x = { int _a = 1; int _b = 2; (1 > 2) ? _a : _b }` is a valid statement in standard C++. I guess that was a question.

Comment: @delnan: Addressed.The title was misleading in the sense it gave the impression that OP thinks it is a namespace returning a value and that is the non-standard part.It is not, it is the use of *statement expression* that is the non-standard part in the code.

Comment: @delnan: I don't think `typeof` is standard either (`decltype` would be the C++11 way to go), so this single macro line is chokeful of gcc extensions indeed :)

Answer (score 7):

This is called a *statement expression*, and is a non-standard [extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs) of GCC. It allows you to use a compound statement as an expression, with a value given by the last expression in the compound statement.

It's used here to avoid the problem that function-like macros may evaluate their arguments multiple times, giving unexpected behaviour if those evaluations have side-effects. The macro is carefully written to evaluate `a` and `b` exactly once.

In C++, you should never need to do anything like this - use function templates instead:

```
template <typename T> T max(T const & a, T const & b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

Comment: Dunno... maybe because unlike the macro example your macro cannot take a differently typed `a` and `b` ?

Answer (score 4):

This may be seen as off topic, but the title of this question came up in my web search while looking for a way to return a value from a `{}` block. Then I realized how to do it from standard c++ constructs. I post this for the next person who lands here for the same reason.

To pick up on what [@BRPocock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8344226/1991373) said, lo these 8 years ago, it **is** possible to return a value from a “anonymous scope operator” / “lexical enclosure” — hence use a `{}` block as part of an expression — through the use of **lambda functions**.

(Historical aside: all of the binding forms in Lisp can be written in terms of macros using lambda expressions. Lisp is where the modern term “lambda function” comes from. Lisp was John McCarthy's 1959 procedural embodiment of the theoretical “lambda calculus” of Church and Turning.)

Back to c++, this is a minimal anonymous lambda function, with no lexical capture, no arguments, and an empty body:

```
[](){}
```

This is that function applied to no arguments:

```
[](){}()
```

Here is that function call with some statements in its body:

```
[](){ int i=2; int j=3; return i+j; }()
```

There is some extra “stuff” around it (which *could* be encapsulated with a macro) and it requires explicit use of `return`, but it meets the basic functionality of returning a value from a `{}` block. For example this will print 5:

```
std::cout << [](){ int i=2; int j=3; return i+j; }() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Neat; this appears to be a C++ equivalent of the JS construct known as IIFEs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression

Comment: Thanks @MatthewG, I was not familiar with that, but yes, that looks like the same idea.

Comment: Very nice!!! I think you don't need the first (), because you are not taking arguments. []{xxxx; return xx;}()

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is not Standard C++, because `typeof` is an extension to C++, by GCC. There is another extension, called Statement Extension is used in the code.

Compile your code with `-pedantic` option, it will not compile.

As for the question, it is not namespace. It is just a macro, which gives you maximum of two values.

Answer (score 1):

This a macro, just like any other #DEFINE. Essentially, the compiler replaces MAX(a,b) with the code defined therein. This will return the max value.

Answer (score 1):

The {} operators, in this context, are an "anonymous scope operator" (aka "lexical enclosure," "form," and various other things. They're being used, somewhat akin to a namespace, to limit the scope of _a and _b to within the braces, so they won't conflict with other vars you might have with the same names. "auto" vars defined within the {braces} will be "destroyed" after the closing brace is reached; or, on a non-local transfer, like a "return" or "longjmp". You can't, however, reliably use "goto" to broach them.

You're probably only used to seeing them after "if," "do," "while," and "for" operators, but think of it as a way to generally "bundle" multiple statements into one "slot," just as you would to run multiple statements as the "then" or "else" clause of an "if" (where, leaving out the braces, you have only one statement "slot")

As Mike Seymour pointed out, the ({}) operation is a non-standard GCC extension, which returns the value of the last item evaluated within it. It's very similar to the general scoping operator, except the inherent return at the end.