# Assign scope to variable in C++

Tags: c++, gcc

Have a look at this code, can someone explain me why `a+1;` is assigned to `b`?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int a = 5;

  int b = ({
      std::cout << "inside scope" << std::endl;
      a+1;
  });

  std::cout << "b value: " << b;
}
```

Comment: It is a [statement expression](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8344122/5922757).

Comment: Well, there's at least a [big fat warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c27d7a6ee5891096).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The construct

```
int b = ({
    std::cout << "inside scope" << std::endl;
    a+1;
    });
```

… is not standard C++, but a *language extension* provided by the g++ compiler.

It's called [“statement expression”](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs), and essentially allows you to introduce local variables for a computation.

Since you don't use that, you could just have used a standard C++ [“comma expression”](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) like this:

```
int b = (
    std::cout << "not inside scope" << std::endl,
    a+1
    );
```

In both cases the expressions in the sequence are evaluated in order, and the value of the expression as a whole is the value of the last evaluation.

---

Where you absolutely need to introduce variables, or e.g. a loop, for the computation in an initializer, you can do that with a standard C++ lambda:

```
int b = [&](){
    double bah = 3.14;
    std::cout << "inside scope" << std::endl;
    return a+!!bah;
    }();
```

In C++17 and later you can use [`std::invoke`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) to make such code more clear, without the JavaScript'ish `()` invocation at the end but instead the word `invoke` up front.

Comment: Thank you for your fully answer

Answer (score 1):

The value of the scope is the last statement within the scope, so in this case

`b = a + 1 = 5 + 1 = 6`

I don't advise writing code like, it is not very clear.

It is a GCC extension called a statement expression so another good reason not to use it because it is not portable. GCC returns a warning:

`warning: ISO C++ forbids braced-groups within expressions [-Wpedantic]`